# How is it out of range when after adding Line 23?

Tags: python-3.x

'''A list rotation consists of taking the first element and moving it to the end.
For instance, if we rotate the list [1,2,3,4,5], we get [2,3,4,5,1]. If we rotate it again, we get [3,4,5,1,2].

Write a Python function rotatelist(l,k) that takes a list l and a positive integer k and returns the list l after k rotations.
If k is not positive, your function should return l unchanged.
Note that your function should not change l itself, and should return the rotated list.'''

```
def rotatelist(l,k):
#checking if the number of rotation is negative
if(k < 0):
    print(l)
    quit()
x=0
#concat_list will store the data of list that will we collected as per given 
#no of rotation
concat_list=[]

list_len=len(l)

for x in range(0,k):
    
    if(x > list_len):
        x=0
    #adding value of list in position 'x' to concat list
    concat_list.append(l[x])
    x+=1
    # c++ style

#adding the value of concat list to updated list
l=l+concat_list

#cutting the part of list as per given requirement
l=l[x:]

print(l)

rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],12)
```

Comment: This is not valid Python code (indentation).  And how is *what* out of range when you add *what*?

Comment: rotatelist function call is not part of function

Comment: see description man

Comment: As posted, *nothing* is part of function, man.

Comment: i had to do it because it was not taking it as a part of code

Comment: function call is not in function itself. it is not something recursion

Comment: Try with `if(x >= list_len):`, lists are 0 indexed so you're getting out of range with the current check

Comment: That works, Thanks man, although it is not desired output but I will do it on my own. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
my =[1,2,3,4,5]
def rotate(my_list,k):
    list1 =my_list
    for i in range(k):
        a = list1.pop(0)
        list1.append(a)
    return(list1)    
        

print(rotate(my,3))
```